# How should I modify the code to call API and return with array?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to modify my static menu to dynamic sidebar menu.
my Core UI file (TheSidebar.tsx) accepts _naigation.js as a array.
Here is what I want to modify in _navigation.js

1. before rendering, call axios to get data for dynamic menu title
2. after receiving response, update static title (ex Menu1, Menu2) to {apiResult.[0]} for dynamic menu.
3. return array

How should I insert api call in _navigation.js and return array to TheSidebar.tsx?

Please allow me to share your kind advicee.

TheSidebar.tsx

```
return (
    <CSidebar>
       ...
      <CSidebarNav>
       ...
       ...
        <CCreateElement
          items={navigation} // it only accepts array.
          components={{
            CSidebarNavDivider,
            CSidebarNavDropdown,
            CSidebarNavItem,
            CSidebarNavTitle
          }}
        />
)
```

```
const navigation = [
  {
    _tag: 'CSidebarNavItem',
    name: 'Menu1', //should change to dynamic data ex) menu2 --> {responseResult.[2]}
    to: '/dashboard',
    icon: <CIcon name="cil-speedometer" customClasses="c-sidebar-nav-icon" />,
    badge: {
      color: 'primary',
      text: 'haha',
    },
  },
  {
    _tag: 'CSidebarNavItem',
    name: 'Menu 2', //should change to dynamic data ex) menu2 --> {responseResult.[2]}
    to: '/dashboard',
    icon: <CIcon name="cil-speedometer" customClasses="c-sidebar-nav-icon" />,
    badge: {
      color: 'primary',
      text: 'haha',
    },
  },
];

export default navigation;
```

Comment: Usually you would use `useState` to store the API results and a `useEffect` with an empty dependency array to initiate the API call when the component is mounted.  Your `useEffect` calls `setState` when it gets the data.

Comment: so you mean, first create functional component. second, set useState with useEffect and lastly return result as a array. it would be fine enough?